# IncompatibleClassChangeError at Unified Native Ads on Android

Tags: android, proguard, native-ads

We are getting errors constantly about unified native ads that Google kind of newly introduced and [this is the documentation link.](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native-unified) At least 0.2% of the errors are from this situation so it actually is important and I don't think it's a bug in the SDK as well, because I didn't find any questions or discussions about it. Also there is nothing noted about this in the documentation. Here is the stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.m' does not implement interface 'com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.f' in call to 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.f.a(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, boolean)' (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.nativead.bb.run(Unknown Source:10)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Now, let me cover some things up about the details about it as I cannot share any source code about this:

- This exception is thrown in devices that has **API 22 only.**
- Our application uses proguard and it does not have a specific setting about keeping the classes of native ads. (I don't think this is the issue because of specific API errors only, and the SDK is already obfuscated in itself.)
- We are loading ads in the application class and show them almost immediately when the related screen opens (it mostly has a delay of 150ms.)

Does anyone have facing the same issue? Or can you suggest a workaround for this kind of error? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a SDK problem. Many people talked about this. Google teams haven't solve it.[Click here to see details.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/2PYBCZTm86Q/JINAZCEFBwAJ)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will look into it. At least I am relaxed that it does not appear from my work on this.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul You're welcome. I have also been trying to solve it. If you have any progress in the future, let me know.